# Animate the CSS transition property within :after/:before pseudo-classes

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

Is it possible to animate CSS pseudo-classes?

Say I have:

```
#foo:after {
    content: '';
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#foo:hover:after {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Is this even possible? I've been testing and so far I can't seem to find a solution. I'm trying to trim down the amount of JavaScript support I need by using Modernizr.

I already have a JavaScript method, so please no JavaScript alternatives.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/MxTvw/

Comment: Good question. What are you using the `::after` element for?

Comment: @minitech Doesn't really matter what I'm using it for, the context of that doesn't change whether it will work or not. I already have a JS alternative of injecting divs etc but I figure, if I don't need to use JS, why use it. Hence the amazing Modernizr ;)

Comment: No, I mean "it apparently won't work, so maybe there's a better CSS3 alternative that you don't know about" :)

Comment: The question is basically a minimal interpretation of what I'm doing, I need the hover to animate the pseudo, not sure there's an alternative? lol

Comment: this WebKit bug was fixed as of yesterday: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your fiddle does work for me in Firefox. And as far as I know, and if [this article](http://css-tricks.com/13555-transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/) is up to date this is the only browser that can animate pseudo-elements.

---

**EDIT**: As of 2016, the link to article is broken and the [relevant WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92591) was [fixed](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632) **4 years ago**. Read on to see other answers, this one is obsolete.

Comment: Don't suppose you know a way for modernizr to detect whether it can animate?

Comment: If I understand correctly how modernizr works it tests for properties in element's style object. To do this with pseudo-elements you'll need a way to get hold of pseudo-element's style object, and I don't thing it's possible. But I may (and wish to be) wrong. If so somebody please correct me.

Comment: this WebKit bug was fixed as of yesterday: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632

Comment: @mik01aj the link can now be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)

Answer (score 12):

**Google Chrome added the webkit bug fix to Version 27.0.1453.110 m**

This WebKit bug was fixed: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632

**IT IS POSSIBLE** to animate pseudo `:before` and `:after`, here are a couple of examples for animating the psuedo-elements `:before` and `:after`.

Here is a modification of your example above with some edits, that make it animate in and out more smoothly without the simulated `mouseleave` / `mouseout` delay on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/MxTvw/234/

Try adding the main selector `#foo` with the grouped `:hover` pseudo-class in your second `:hover` pseudo-class rule. Also add the `transition` property, and not just the vendor specific prefixed properties for `transition`:

```
#foo:after{
   display: block;
   content: '';
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
} 

#foo,
#foo:hover:after,
#foo:hover:before{
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
}
```

Note that going forward any Pseudo Elements like `:before` and `:after` should use the double colon syntax `::before` and `::after`. This example simulates a fade in and out using a overlay `background-color` and a `background-image` on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/MxTvw/233/

This example simulates a animate of rotation on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jm54S/28/

Of course moving forward with css3 standards we could use `::before` and `::after`.

**This works in latest Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera 18+, IE10, IE11** (IE9 and below do not support css3 transitions or animate.)

Comment: Pseudo-classes are not pseudo-elements. The entire point of introducing that double colon syntax was so that people wouldn't get the two mixed up. Oh and this has already been suggested many times over, and all do not work in WebKit.

Comment: the above questions asked about 'animate' pseudo :before and :after .. css3 transitions are buggy in latest version WebKit.. css3 animation and transforms animate just fine.. [https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23209]

Comment: corrected link to bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23209  and this http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/88308 showing patch has been applied but not working right.. also some work-arounds found here on comment 51 - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54699

Comment: as far as referring to : before and :after as pseudo classes I was mistaken and meant pseudo elements, thank you very much for your type correction! .

Comment: this webkit bug fix has been added in latest chrome: Version 27.0.1453.110 m - nice!

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for the heads up... It works in Opera 18+ .. Opera switched their rendering engine to the same as Google Chrome in version 18 .. so Opera uses webkit now. Opera 18+ and up support animating ::before and ::after pseudo elements, just like Google Chrome

Comment: The `-ms-transition` prefix is not used by any stable version of IE and should be removed (it wasn't in the question to begin with for a reason). The unprefixed declaration should be at the bottom.

Comment: @BoltClock I changed the order .. removed ms, thanks.. My answer was written in 2012.. so sorry my answer had old ways of doing stuff that Microsoft recommended at the time .. Regarding order of properties.. I have seen no difference in how the vendor prefix and standard property are ordered when your prefixed properties contain only one value. But if the property has more than one value, i notice the order matters on properties with more than one value..  But i agree with you that the non prefixed property should be last.. but thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

It [does not seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/Lapple/QEHbv/) now, however according to the [W3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#the-transition-property-property-) you can apply transitions to pseudo-elements. Maybe some time in future…

Answer (score -3):

I just found out that you can animate :after and :before (:

Code example-

```
  .model-item {
    position: relative;

    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: transparent;
      transition: all .3s;
    }
  }

  .opc {
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 51, 92, .75);
    }
  }
```

I have the div .model-item and i needed to animate his :after.
So i've added another class which changes background and i added the transition code to the main :after (before animation)

Comment: Works with Chrome as well