# CSS rotation not working

Tags: css

I am testing some css animation and cant get this elements :before to rotate, any help?

http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/hZjkp/5/

CSS

```
.footerLink{
    padding:20px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
.footerLink:before{
    content:'ABC';
    margin-right:15px;
    -webkit-animation: footerHoverOff .5s ease both;
    -moz-animation: footerHoverOff .5s ease both;
    animation: footerHoverOff .5s ease both;
}
.footerLink:hover:before{
    -webkit-animation: footerHoverOn .5s ease both;
    -moz-animation: footerHoverOn .5s ease both;
    animation: footerHoverOn .5s ease both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes footerHoverOn{ to { -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg); } }
@-moz-keyframes footerHoverOn{ to { -moz-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes footerHoverOn{ to { transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes footerHoverOff{ from { -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg); } }
@-moz-keyframes footerHoverOff{ from { -moz-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes footerHoverOff{ from { transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg); } }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809872/animate-a-css-after-before-pseudo

Comment: It is not a duplicate, if you see the code in question, you can notice my approach is on keyframes and not on simple css animations.

Comment: Try adding `display:inline-block;` to the `.footerLink:before` selector.

Comment: If _simple_ animations don't work why would keyframed ones do?

Comment: I've got the answer above already, you should read it to see the difference between both questions, as it is no were in the post you say its a duplicate of.

Comment: try following this question it should help
  
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809872/animate-a-css-after-before-pseudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, this isn't how you go about css keyframe animation.  You are confusing the syntax with transtions.

With keyframe animation:

```
.footerLink{
padding:20px;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
.footerLink:before{
    content:'ABC';
    margin-right:15px;
}
.footerLink:before:hover {
    animation: footerHover .5s;
}
@keyframes footerHover { 
    from { transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

With transitions:

```
.footerLink{
    padding:20px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
.footerLink:before{
    content:'ABC';
    margin-right:15px;
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0deg);
    transition: .5s;
}
.footerLink:before:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Where am I confusing the syntax?

Comment: Keyframes have to have a 'from' and 'to', or '0%' and '100%'.  If you don't have a start and end point it will be ignored.  When you want to define a start point by default and an end point on :hover, you should use a transition not animation.