# Making pseudo-element appear, and then disappear again after X amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to manipulate the :before pseudo-element of my body tag to appear after a certain amount of time, and then disappear again after a couple of seconds.

```
body:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #color;
}
```

So, essentially, I am trying to display this full viewport overlay with the pseudo-element after X amount of seconds, and then after some time has passed, I want to remove it again!

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't with js but cosider using css animation like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809872/animate-the-css-transition-property-within-after-before-pseudo-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this with pure CSS:

```css
body:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  animation: show 5s ease-out forwards;
  
}

@keyframes show{
  0%{
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20%{
    content: "";
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%{
    content: "";
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    content: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
Hello World!
```

To choose the duration just adjust the number before the letter "s" which indicates the second:

```
animation: show ***5s*** ease-out forwards;
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea, what a nice way to solve this.

I ended up modifying it a bit, since I needed the overlay to appear after a certain amount of time. This can be done with by adding a delay to the animation like so

`animation-delay: 50s;`


Another thing that I ended up doing here, was removing the display attribute, since it will make you unable to interact with site content before the content of the pseudo-element has been cleared. The way I instead solved this, was using the "Visibility" attribute!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot manipulate pseudo elements, since they're not in DOM.

But! Using a class that can be removed, you can achieve that.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $("body").removeClass("red");
},2000);
```

```css
body{
  height:2000px;
}

body.red:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="red">
Blah blah bla... Ya ya ya...
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change pseudo elements in JS because it can only manipulate DOM elements

So what I would do is set up a create a class in JavaScript and remove it after 4 seconds

Here is my method:

HTML

```
<body class="ID">
```

CSS

```
.ID:before {
     content: " ";
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 100;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     background: red;
     }
```

JavaScript

```
setTimeout(() => {
document.querySelector('.ID').classList.remove('ID')
}, 4000);
```